# Email Reports through Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a pdf generated by Dynamic Reports.I want to add this pdf as an attachment in the mail feature of Jenkins for each and every build of the project.Is It possible to achieve this.Is there any another way in which I can mail my reports through Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) for Jenkins. It provides more configuration options than "standard Jenkins" emails. Also it gives you opportunity add attachments to your emails:

> Attachments
>
> New to version 2.15 is the ability to add attachments using the Ant pattern matching syntax used in many places in Jenkins. You can set a maximum total attachment size in the global configuration page, or it will be unlimited.

Comment: Is It necessary that the pdf be present in workspace?

Comment: I have placed the pdf in a folder and have included the folder path in custom workspace.and have specified the ant pattern as *.pdf but still no success